# SSH stalled after a while

Tags: ssh, tcp, sftp, centos7

I am executing some commands over SSH from a linux client (centos 7) toward a server (wind river linux) and for a reason it always stopped ( not completed ).
If i executed a command that take short time to complete, it will be successful.

What i am doing:

```
ssh user@server1 'command1;command2;command3;command4;command5'
```

command4 is taking maybe about 1 minute to complete, but in my case it didn't complete.

I run the same chain of commands to another similar server, it works just fine.

There is firewall between my linux client and server and I am suspecting it. But since it is out of my control, I have to dig further first in my client and server.

I run tcpdump several times while running the command and I found that it always stalled at `TCP ACK 9336`.

[image]

[image]

Did anybody ever have similar problem?

Comment: Do you have KeepAlive set to yes in your clients ~/.ssh/config ? If not, maybe you should try it with: 
Host *
KeepAlive yes
ServerAliveInterval 15?

Comment: Thank Jakov, i tried the suggestion, but the problem still persist. I check with FW guy, they checked the log and according to the log session are created in FW. But they can not see if there is TCP retransmission or not during the SSH session.